# reading json from jquery

Tags: json, jquery

Hi everyone I am trying to read some json and do 2 things.
Insert some of the json data into a UL. Second thing is create a function that can be called from a anchor tag and displays the other data.Let me try explain with my code.

My json looks like this

```
[{lakeName:"Lake 1",lakeCode:"111",Readings[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5],]}{lakeName:"Lake 2",lakeCode:"222",Readings[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5],]}]
```

I am trying to populate my list like this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://theaboveJSONisreturnedFromMyUrl",
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: onDataReceived
        });



        var data = [];

        function onDataReceived(series) {

            data = [series];
            $(data).each(function (i, data) {
                $('#myList').append("<li>" + "<a href=\"javascript:GetLake(" + data.lakeCode + ");\">" + data.lakeName + "</a></li>");
            });

        }
    });

          function GetLake(lake) {

          alert('some how get the readings for the clicked lake code e.g. lakeCode 111 and display them here ["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5] );

          }
```

Now I see values in data however I cant seem to access the through e.g. data.lakeCode

What have I done wrong?

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: At first glance, I'd guess you have a syntax error in your JSON. I'd think that a `:` is missing after `Readings`. That may or may not be the whole problem.

Comment: Also `data = [series];` makes `series` the only item in the array `data`.  You then try to iterate over the array using `$.each`.  This is identical to working directly on `series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your JSON. It should look like this:

```
[{lakeName:"Lake 1",lakeCode:"111",Readings:[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5]]},{lakeName:"Lake 2",lakeCode:"222",Readings:[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5]]}]
```

Some `:` and `,` were missing, unnecessary `,` in between and an unneeded `]` was at the end.

Comment: Cool. Iwill work on getting the json syntax sorted. Hopefully that will help.
I have taken away data =[series] however series.lakeCode still is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

when your are not sure of your JSON's syntax just check it with that:
http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

To be valid, your JSON needs the following changes ([you can check always validity with JSONLint here](http://www.jsonlint.com/)):

- Commas between objects in the main array
- No trailing commands in the `Readings` arrays
- Double quotes around member names
- `:` between `Readings` and its value

Over all it should look like this:

```
[{"lakeName":"Lake 1","lakeCode":"111","Readings":[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5] ]},{"lakeName":"Lake 2","lakeCode":"222","Readings":[["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5] ]}]
//compared to your current version:
[{ lakeName :"Lake 1", lakeCode :"111", Readings  [["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5],]} { lakeName :"Lake 2", lakeCode :"222", Readings  [["24-Oct-10",12.5],["24-Oct-10",10.5],["24-Oct-10",15.5],]}]
```

Also, you should use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) here instead , like this:

```
$.each(data, function () {
  $('#myList').append("<li>" + "<a href=\"javascript:GetLake(" + this.lakeCode + ");\">" + this.lakeName + "</a></li>");
});
```

Or a bit better, use DOM methods like this:

```
$.each(data, function () {
  $('<a />', { href: '#', click: function() { GetLake(this.lakeCode); } })
     .wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo('#myList');
});
```

Comment: Ok so I have got my json validated and looking good. However this.lakeCode is been returned still as undefined.  What else have I missed??

Comment: @user293545 - my fault, didn't see your `data = [series];`, just use `series` directly.

Comment: cool thanks Nick. javascript is a weakness for me :( Ok so in my function GetLake how is my best way to get to the Readings objects and output them? Should I have a variable somewhere?